# changing wireless beacon interval

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there any possible ways to change beacon interval in linux. I have atheros chipset using ath9k driver. I know it is possible to to use iw command to set the beacon interval but still i am confused about the use of the command. Also how do i know the current beacon interval

What i  want is to make a ad hoc networks between two devices using ubuntu 12.04 and beaconing interval lower than the normal values.

This is the output that i get when i run the iw command.

```
iw iwphy2 set beacon-interval 25
Usage:  iw [options] command
Options:
    --debug     enable netlink debugging
    --version   show version (3.2)
Commands:
    help
    event [-t] [-r] [-f]
    phy
    list
    phy <phyname> info
    dev
    dev <devname> info
    dev <devname> del
    dev <devname> interface add <name> type <type> [mesh_id <meshid>] [4addr on|off] [flags <flag>*]
    phy <phyname> interface add <name> type <type> [mesh_id <meshid>] [4addr on|off] [flags <flag>*]
    dev <devname> ibss join <SSID> <freq in MHz> [fixed-freq] [<fixed bssid>] [beacon-interval <TU>] [basic-rates <rate in Mbps,rate2,...>] [mcast-rate <rate in Mbps>] [key d:0:abcde]
    dev <devname> ibss leave
    dev <devname> station dump
    dev <devname> station set <MAC address> vlan <ifindex>
    dev <devname> station set <MAC address> plink_action <open|block>
    dev <devname> station del <MAC address>
    dev <devname> station get <MAC address>
    dev <devname> survey dump
    dev <devname> mesh leave
    dev <devname> mesh join <mesh ID> [<param>=<value>]*
    dev <devname> mpath dump
    dev <devname> mpath set <destination MAC address> next_hop <next hop MAC address>
    dev <devname> mpath new <destination MAC address> next_hop <next hop MAC address>
    dev <devname> mpath del <MAC address>
    dev <devname> mpath get <MAC address>
    dev <devname> scan [-u] [freq <freq>*] [ies <hex as 00:11:..>] [ssid <ssid>*|passive]
    dev <devname> scan trigger [freq <freq>*] [ies <hex as 00:11:..>] [ssid <ssid>*|passive]
    dev <devname> scan dump [-u]
    reg get
    reg set <ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2>
    dev <devname> connect [-w] <SSID> [<freq in MHz>] [<bssid>] [key 0:abcde d:1:6162636465]
    dev <devname> disconnect
    dev <devname> link
    dev <devname> offchannel <freq> <duration>
    dev <devname> cqm rssi <threshold|off> [<hysteresis>]
    phy <phyname> wowlan show 
    phy <phyname> wowlan disable 
    phy <phyname> wowlan enable [any] [disconnect] [magic-packet] [gtk-rekey-failure] [eap-identity-request] [4way-handshake] [rfkill-release] [patterns <pattern>*]
    dev <devname> roc start <freq> <time>
    phy <phyname> set antenna <bitmap> | all | <tx bitmap> <rx bitmap>
    dev <devname> set txpower <auto|fixed|limit> [<tx power in mBm>]
    phy <phyname> set txpower <auto|fixed|limit> [<tx power in mBm>]
    phy <phyname> set distance <distance>
    phy <phyname> set coverage <coverage class>
    phy <phyname> set netns <pid>
    phy <phyname> set rts <rts threshold|off>
    phy <phyname> set frag <fragmentation threshold|off>
    dev <devname> set channel <channel> [HT20|HT40+|HT40-]
    phy <phyname> set channel <channel> [HT20|HT40+|HT40-]
    dev <devname> set freq <freq> [HT20|HT40+|HT40-]
    phy <phyname> set freq <freq> [HT20|HT40+|HT40-]
    phy <phyname> set name <new name>
    dev <devname> set peer <MAC address>
    dev <devname> set 4addr <on|off>
    dev <devname> set type <type>
    dev <devname> set meshid <meshid>
    dev <devname> set monitor <flag>*
    dev <devname> set mesh_param <param>=<value> [<param>=<value>]*
    dev <devname> set power_save <on|off>
    dev <devname> set bitrates [legacy-<2.4|5> <legacy rate in Mbps>*]
    dev <devname> get mesh_param [<param>]
    dev <devname> get power_save <param>

You can omit the 'phy' or 'dev' if the identification is unique,
e.g. "iw wlan0 info" or "iw phy0 info". (Don't when scripting.)

Do NOT screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable.
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

While in ad-hoc-mode you cannot change the beacon interval unless leaving and joining again.

```
iw dev <devname> ibss join <SSID> <freq in MHz> [HT20|HT40+|HT40-|NOHT] [fixed-freq] [<fixed bssid>] [beacon-interval <TU>] [basic-rates <rate in Mbps,rate2,...>] [mcast-rate <rate in Mbps>] [key d:0:abcde]
```

While in AP-Mode hostapd sets the interval for you:
in your hostapd.conf set
**beacon_int=1000**
for an interval of 1000ms=1s.

while in station-mode the interval is set through your wpa_supplicant's setting.